# Editing pythonpath for every script in a project

Tags: python, coding-style, python-import, organization

So I structure almost all of my projects like this:

root/
|- scripts/
|- src/
|- etc. ...

I put runnable scripts in scripts/ and importable modules in src/, and by convention run every script from the root directory (so I always stay in root, then type 'python scripts/*whatever*')

In order to be able to import code from src/, I've decided to start every script with this:

```
import sys
import os
# use this to make sure we always have the dir we ran from in path
sys.path.append(os.getcwd())
```

To make sure root/ is always in the path for scripts being run from root.

My question is: is this considered bad style?  I like my conventions of always running scripts from the root directory, and keeping my scripts separate from my modules, but it seems like a weird policy to always edit the path variable for every script I write.

If this is considered bad style, could you provide alternative recommendations?  Either different ways for me to keep my existing conventions or recommendations for different ways to structure projects would be great!

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

My recommendation is to use:

```
root/$ python -m scripts.whatever
```

With the `-m` you use the `.` notation rather than the file path and you won't need to setup path code in each of the scripts because the `-m` tells Python to start looking for imports in the directory where you called Python.

If your file structure also happens to be installed using `setup.py` and may be found within the `site_packages` there are some other things to consider:

1. If you call `-m` from the root of the directory structure (as I've shown above) it will call the code found in your directories
2. If you call `-m` from anywhere else, it will find the installed code from `sys.path` and call that

This can be a subtle gotcha if you happen to be running an interpreter that has your package installed and you are trying to make changes to your scripts locally and can't figure out why your changes aren't there (this happened to a coworker of mine who wasn't using virtual environments).